# Using sed, Insert a line above or below the pattern?

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I need to edit a good number of files, by inserting a line or multiple lines either right below a unique pattern or above it. Please advise on how to do that using `sed`, `awk`, `perl` (or anything else) in a shell. Thanks! Example:

```
some text
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
more text
```

I want to insert `consectetur adipiscing elit` after `lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`, so the output file will look like:

```
some text
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit
more text
```

Comment: This was what showed up on Google much before the linked duplicate. Edited for grammar, style and example contents because of that.

Answer (score 176):

To append after the pattern: (-i is for in place replace). line1 and line2 are the lines you want to append(or prepend)

```
sed -i '/pattern/a \
line1 \
line2' inputfile
```

**Output:**

```
#cat inputfile
 pattern
 line1 line2
```

To prepend the lines before:

```
sed -i '/pattern/i \
line1 \
line2' inputfile
```

**Output:**

```
#cat inputfile
 line1 line2 
 pattern
```

Comment: The examples insert a space after `line1` (tested with GNU sed). The backslash should follow without a space: ``line1\``. Only the spaces after the `a` and `i` commands are ignored.

Comment: how to mix the prepend while reading the lines from another file where `sed -i '/pattern/ r somefile.txt'`?

Comment: To avoid inserting space, just remove space between `i` (or `a`) character and `\`.

Comment: @AquariusPower In GNU sed, `/pattern/e cat somefile.txt` which will stick `somefile.txt` into the pattern space before `/pattern/`.  This can be mroe useful that `r` which just sticks `somefile.txt` directly into the output stream.

Comment: to test it leave the i flag.

Answer (score 43):

The following adds one line after `SearchPattern`.

`sed -i '/SearchPattern/aNew Text' SomeFile.txt`

It inserts `New Text` one line below each line that contains `SearchPattern`.

To add **two lines**, you can use a `\` and enter a newline while typing `New Text`.

POSIX sed requires a `\` and a newline after the `a` sed function. [1]
Specifying the text to append without the newline is a GNU sed extension (as documented in the `sed` info page), so its usage is not as portable.

[1] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52131/sed-on-osx-insert-at-a-certain-line/

Comment: One-liner example makes it easier for me to understand, and most-applicable for most of my use-cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Insert a new verse after the given verse in your stanza:

```
sed -i '/^lorem ipsum dolor sit amet$/ s:$:\nconsectetur adipiscing elit:' FILE
```

Comment: Added an example. Note that 'Hello My love, you're dirty girl' must be the only string on the line.

Comment: @vehomzzz : The pattern below search the line containing the dirty girl. On that line, it execute the command substitute (s) replacing the end-of-line ($) by a return (\n) and the sexy knight line

Comment: I've edited the question and all answers that refered to the questions' example. Just pointing it out so you can edit your comments accordingly if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 6):

More portable to use ed; some systems don't support \n in sed

```
printf "/^lorem ipsum dolor sit amet/a\nconsectetur adipiscing elit\n.\nw\nq\n" |\
    /bin/ed $filename
```

Comment: Note that you can add -*n* and +n commands, where *n* is any integer, to move up or down and therefore insert lines anywhere necessary in the region of the search string.

Comment: THANKSALOT for a new tool in my toolshed.