# Add/Insert lines before pattern such that lines to be added have part of the pattern in uppercase

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk, sed

I have to add compiler directives before class declaration like :

```
`ifndef MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV
`define MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV

class mipi_rffe_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;
```

I tried :

```
sed 's/class (\w+)(.*)/\`ifndef \U\1__SV\2/' mipi_rffe_scoreboard.sv
```

Which gives :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

I have seen [Using sed, Insert a line below (or above) the pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694980/using-sed-insert-a-line-below-or-above-the-pattern). Here Kamal's answer solves only the part of the problem as I need to capture "mipi_rffe_scoreboard" and change it to uppercase

Comment: Please take care with your formatting. To highlight a block of code, you can select it and use Ctrl-k, or click the "Code Sample" button.

Comment: @anubhava I was reluctant to edit as it is unclear whether the "\" and "**" are part of the input. Hopefully Chandan will edit to clarify.

Comment: I was trying to highlight those with bold font.I am getting `ifndef and `define using sed -i '/pattern/i \
line1 \
line2' inputfile but need the MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV also

Comment: It is not possible to combine formatting with code samples. If you want to draw attention to a specific part, you can mention it in the question. Any characters that are not in your original input should be removed.

Comment: Also include your expected output.

Comment: @Tom No need I think it looks okay now.

Comment: @anubhava my file has only : class mipi_rffe_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard; line at present I need to make it like : `ifndef MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV
`define MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV

class mipi_rffe_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;

Comment: Did you try the code I suggested? Let me know if you're having any problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this perl one-liner on your file:

```
perl -pe 's/(class (\w+))/`ifndef \U$2\E__SV\n`define \U$2\E__SV\n\n$1/'
```

It captures lines containing "class" followed by a word and prepends the two lines. `\U` is used to transform the match to uppercase and `\E` to end the transformation.

Testing it out:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(class (\w+))/`ifndef \U$2\E__SV\n`define \U$2\E__SV\n\n$1/'  <<<"class mipi_rffe_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;"
`ifndef MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV
`define MIPI_RFFE_SCOREBOARD__SV

class mipi_rffe_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;
```

Alternatively (tested on GNU sed, I'm fairly confident that this won't work on other versions):

```
sed -r 's/class (\w+)/`ifndef \U\1\E__SV\n`define \U\1\E__SV\n\n&/'
```

`-r` enables extended regex mode, which allows you to use `( )` to capture patterns. Normally, you would have to escape them using `\( \)`.