# How do I reverse Engineer with hibernate to get mapped superclass

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, mappedsuperclass

I have six tables that have many common fields.

Ten years ago I specified something to Hibernate Reverse Engineering to create a mapped superclass and six classes that extend that class.

I could do it manually, but I am sure the capability must still be there.

After two hours of googling and seeing example of hand crafted pojos, I can't find how to get reveng to do it.

Comment: I am not asking for code, I just can't find the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure it out.  Instead I wrote an Interface and an abstract class and then modified the generated code.

Not pretty, but it actually has more benefits to me.

Strangely enough the class I extend must have a setter method for every property or the application fails to load.

I have created setters that just throw UnsupportedOperationException

Now if could just get two source trees in this project and have the target classes generated by hibernate compile without this nonsense.

```
apply() {
FILE=$1
echo $FILE
return
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694980/using-sed-insert-a-line-below-or-above-the-pattern
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148451/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-only-the-first-occurrence-in-a-file
sed -i -e "0,/implements/{s/implements/extends AbstractDemand implements/}" $FILE

sed -i -e "3i  \
import com.techwanker.diamond.planning.AbstractDemand;\\n\
import com.techwanker.diamond.planning.AllocationMode;\\n\
import com.techwanker.diamond.planning.demand.DemandType;\\n\
" $FILE 
}

find_file() {
   file=`locate $1 | grep "^$PWD" | grep $1\$`
   return $file


rm -rf src/main/java
mvn hibernate3:hbm2java
apply `find_file ApsDmdOo.java`
apply `find_file ApsDmdSs.java`
apply `find_file ApsDmdFc.java`



cp -r src/main/java-required/java/* src/main/java
cp -r target/generated-sources/* src/main/java
mvn install
```