# Add line to ClearCase config

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-automation

I am running a job on Jenkins which is used to create a view on ClearCase and the ClearCase view creates the default config spec.

I want to edit the config spec by adding some more lines to it but I don't want to edit it manually every time. So I am looking to add some script to Jenkins so that it can edit the configspec every time when it runs the job.

Is there anyone how is clear case expert who can task it out.

Comment: If you can generate the config spec by script, you can then call cleartool setcs (name of the file) in order to set that generated config spec in the created view. That can by done as a first step

Comment: Yes but I am looking for the script which can add more lines to existing configspec.

Answer (score 1):

Once your ClearCase view is created you need to get its config spec as a file with [`cleartool edcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm)

```
cd /path/to/view
cleartool catcs > cs
```

You need to adds your selection rules *before* the default one: as mentioned in [config spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)

> Because the rules in a config spec are processed in order, varying the order may affect version selection. For example, suppose this rule appears near the beginning of a config spec:

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

> Any subsequent rules in the config spec will never be used, because the rule always provides a match; every element has a most recent version on its main branch.
>
> Note:
>   The order in which the load rules for a snapshot view are specified is not important.

To script that, please see "[Using `sed`, Insert a line below (or above) the pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694980/6309)".
Another option: see "[How to insert the content of a file into another file before a pattern (marker)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32915/7490)".
Put your additional lines into a file named `othercs`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ .*CHECKEDOUT.*$ ]]
    then
        cat othercs
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < cs
```

Once that is done, you can append any additional load rules you want (if you are using a snapshot view, since a dynamic view has no load rules)

Finally, once the cs file has the right selection/load rules, you set it back to the current view with [`cleartool setcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm).

```
cleartool setcs -tag view-tag  cs
                              ^
                              |
                     name of the file you have modified
```

Comment: @bri yes, I have fixed that typo

Comment: I tried to add the additional lines using sed but I failed in doing that. Can you please help me out in detail.
More details are added below .

Comment: @clearclase I have edite my answer to propose an alternative in order to insert your selection rules into an existing config spec.