# I want to insert a line into my file after "target 'cheney11' do",how to finish it with sed?

Tags: sed

my file Like this:

```
cheney
fang
130034
target 'cheney11' do
    pod xxx
end
target 'cheney22' do
    pod xxx 
end
```

and I want to insert a line which is

```
:git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'" afert "target 'cheney11' do
```

sot that the result looks like this:

```
cheney
fang
130034
target 'cheney11' do
    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'
    inerset a line like 
    pod xxx
end
target 'cheney22' do
    pod xxx 
end
```

note: there are five space before `:git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'`

Comment: it is **4** spaces before the `":git...."` in your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed, Insert a line below (or above) the pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694980/using-sed-insert-a-line-below-or-above-the-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a \
>    text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash

```
$ sed "/target 'cheney11'/a \
\    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'" file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
cheney
fang
130034
target 'cheney11' do
        pod xxx
end
target 'cheney22' do
        pod xxx
end

kent$  sed "/target 'cheney11'/a \
\    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'" f
cheney
fang
130034
target 'cheney11' do
    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'
        pod xxx
end
target 'cheney22' do
        pod xxx
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let us know if this helps you.

```
awk '
/target \047cheney11\047 do/{
  print "    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>\047master\047" ORS $0;
  next
}
1' Input_file
```

Append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code in case you want to save output of it to same Input_file too.

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `sed` as follows.

```
sed "s/target 'cheney11' do/    :git=>www.google.com, :branch=>'master'\n&/" Input_file
```

Kindly use either `sed -i.bak` to take backup + save changes into Input_file OR `sed -i` option to only save output into Input_file itself.