# How To Use SED Command To Insert A Line Before A Pattern Match

Tags: linux, unix, sed

After running command `sed -i "/class MySQLPagedResultsajax/i Thing I Wish To Add;" /File/Location/`

The result I get are as follows:

```
Thing I Wish To Add;class MySQLPagedResultsajax
```

Whereas I want to achieve this:

```
Thing I Wish To Add;
class MySQLPagedResultsajax
```

Please Help As I Want A Single Line Command Solution As This Needs To Be Done On Multiple Files And I Will Be Using Excel To Create Separate Commands For Each File.

Comment: That is odd and I can't reproduce it, `i` should insert a proper separate line (see the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Inserting-text-before-a-line)). What version of sed are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed, Insert a line above or below the pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694980/608639)

Comment: GNU sed version 4.2.1
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-gnu-utils@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.

Comment: I Want A Single Line Command Solution and hence this is not duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/class MySQLPagedResultsajax/s/^/Thing I Wish To Add;\n/'
```

Or before you are sure, try this first and check the output on console:

```
sed -e '/class MySQLPagedResultsajax/s/^/Thing I Wish To Add;\n/'
```

`s` is the **s**ubstitute command.
`^` means the beginning of the line.
`\n` a newline.

Comment: I ran it and the results were still the same

Thing I Wish To Add;class MySQLPagedResultsajax

Comment: @RishiSachdeva  I need to confirm this: You want a newline after `Thing I Wish To Add;`, before `class`, right?  Also are you using these commands inside another environment, which is not directly inside bash/shell? Please try produce [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk for anything other than a simple s/old/new:

```
awk '/class MySQLPagedResultsajax/{print "Thing I Wish To Add;"} 1' file
```

add `-i inplace` to do pseudo-inplace editing with GNU awk like you can do pseudo-inplace editing with GNU sed by adding `-`i.

Comment: I could not use -i since i am not using the latest version of awk so i moved the output to a temporary file but the results are still the same

Thing I Wish To Add;class MySQLPagedResultsajax

Comment: Then you have some kind of control characters in your input or in your code or you're doing something else to block printing of newlines. Use `cat -v` to see control chars.